# How to print real time waveforms in thermal printer?

Tags: c++, printing

I want to print real time  data waveforms/graphs for eg. a sinewave.
I can print text & barcodes on my thermal printer , but how can I print waveforms?
My printer data sheet has commands for character, bitmap,NV Bitmap & Bar codes.

Are there any special commands to print waveform?

I'am coding in C++ language. 
Any logic or algorithm will be a great help!

Comment: While we have no idea about your particular model of printer, the likely answer is no. But that should not matter: you're a programmer, program something. Turn that waveform into a bitmap and print that.

Comment: Hello MSalters, Thanks for your reply. I was thinking the same thing & trying the implement it. My printer is a chinese printer mechanism which is Fujistu FTP-638mc101 compatible. I've seen printers which have direct commands to print Vertical & Horizontal line. Converting the data into Bitmap and then printing can be one of the ways. Will try and achieve it through the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal printers usually works on line data, ie. 1 bit = 1 Pixel, so if you have 1728 pixels in a vertical line you need to provide 216 bytes to the print head. Usually vertical resolution is fixed and horizontal resolution can be manipulated by playing around with motor speed.

Coming back to your question, Printer's usually does not provide API's for such real time waveform printing. You need to generate line data by processing data samples and push it to the print head.